# Checking IP like address list with Prolog

Tags: list, parsing, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to build a predicate that given a list (eg. `['1', '2', '3', '.', ... , '2']`) it has to recognise it as an IP string in the format `(NNN.NNN.NNN.NNN)` where `N` is a digit (between `0` and `9`) it return true if it is correctly formatted. It must accept also the case where the IP is only (`N.N.N.N` or `NNN.NNN.N.N` and other combinations).

This is what I've done so far

```
test([X,Y,Z,D | String]) :- digit(X), digit(Y), digit(Z), dot(D), test(String).
```

Where digit is a list of facts like `digit('0').` from `0` to `9`; and dot is a fact defined as `dot('.')`. My code lacks of modularity (it can't recognise single `N`). Can you help me achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: For others finding this question. While the question ask for IP (implying IPv4) it does not specify a true IPv4 address. In other words if you use answers for this in production code you could be very sorry. Also it is not checking for IPv6 which is a lot harder as subsections may be dropped entirely and still be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO. I would do it like this:

seperate the input list into 4 "blocks", where the dot is the delimiter and accept only blocks with 1-3 digit elements in them. To do this prolog can be a bit tricky due to the constraints on the length of the numbers (1-3) and the constraints on the dots (exactly 3 dots). So my approach would look like this (basic but a bit twisted):

```
test(In):-
    digits123(In,['.'|R1]),
    digits123(R1,['.'|R2]),
    digits123(R2,['.'|R3]),
    digits123(R3,[]).
    
digits123([A,B,C|R],R):-
    digit(A),
    digit(B),
    digit(C).
digits123([A,B|R],R):-
    digit(A),
    digit(B).
digits123([A|R],R):-
    digit(A).
```

What does it do? `digits123/2` gets as input a list and it checks if either the first 3, 2, or one elements are digits. Also the rest of the list is unified with the second argument, making this a test for the numbers and a generator/test for the rest list. `digits123/2` alone would be buggy since three digits could be mistaken for 2 or one digit. So the call makes it special: at first `digits123/2` is called in the inputlist `In`, returning the list with the remaining elements. But this remaining list has to start with a dot (`['.'|R1]`). By writing it like this, `R1` is the remaining list without the dot as delimiter. Repeat this two times more to check the 2nd and 3rd block. The last block is different: it has 1-3 digits but no dot (or anything else) afterwards. In other words: there should no elements remain (empty list, `[]`).

Tested with SWISH:

```
?- test(['1', '2', '3', '.', '2', '3', '.', '2', '.' , '2']).
true;
false.

?- test(['1', '2', '3', '.', '2', '3', '.', '2', '.' ]).
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

The easies way is to use a DCG grammer to specify what the dotted quad looks like. An IPv4 address is 4 octets, expressed in decimal, and separated by '.'. We can express that as a DCG rule like this:

```
dotted_quad --> octet, dot, octet, dot, octet, dot, octet.
```

The rule for a `.` is trivial:

```
dot --> ['.'].
```

The rule(s) for an octet are more complicated. An octet is constrained to be in the domain 0–255. Represented in decimal it can be

- 0-9:
  A single decimal digit `0`–`9`
- 10-99:
  Two decimal digits, the first in the domain `1`–`9`, the second in the domain `0`–`9`.
- 100-199:
  Three decimal digits. The 1st is `1` and the second and third are in the domain `0`–`9`.
- 200-249:
  Three decimal digits. The first is `2`, the second has the domain `0`–`4`, and the third, `0`–`9`.
- 250–255:
  Three decimal digits. The first is `2`, the second is `5`, and the third is constrained to `0`–`5`.

We can either write a lot of special rules to cover this, or add some context to the rule for a decimal digit. Let's add some context to that rule (because why type more than you need to):

```
digit(D)       --> [D].
digit(Min,Max) --> [D], { D @>= Min, D @=< Max }.
```

These let us say things like `digit('0','5')` to indicate that a digit in the domain 0-5 is allowed, or `digit('2')` to say that only the digit 2 is allowed.

Now that we have that we can define the rules for an octet:

```
octet --> digit('0','9') .
octet --> digit('1','9') , digit('0','9').
octet --> digit('1')     , digit('0','9') , digit('0','9').
octet --> digit('2')     , digit('0','4') , digit('0','9').
octet --> digit('2')     , digit('5')     , digit('0','5').
```

Now we can define our test predicate. All it needs to do is invoke the DCG we defined:

```
is_dotted_quad(Cs) :- phrase(dotted_quad, Cs).
```

But since typing something like

```
[ '1','2','3', '.', '2','3','4', '.', '7','8', '.', '9' ]`
```

is tedious and error-prone, let's add some conveniences to let us use strings or atoms:

```
is_dotted_quad(X)  :- atom(X)   , atom_chars(X,Cs) , is_dotted_quad(Cs) .
is_dotted_quad(X)  :- string(X) , atom_chars(X,Cs) , is_dotted_quad(Cs) .
is_dotted_quad(Cs) :- phrase(dotted_quad, Cs).
```

Putting it all together, you get this:

```
is_dotted_quad(X)  :- atom(X)   , atom_chars(X,Cs)   , is_dotted_quad(Cs).
is_dotted_quad(X)  :- string(X) , string_chars(X,Cs) , is_dotted_quad(Cs).
is_dotted_quad(Cs) :- phrase(dotted_quad, Cs).

dotted_quad --> octet, dot, octet, dot, octet, dot, octet.

dot --> ['.'].

octet --> digit('0','9') .
octet --> digit('1','9') , digit('0','9') .
octet --> digit('1')     , digit('0','9') , digit('0','9').
octet --> digit('2')     , digit('0','4') , digit('0','9').
octet --> digit('2')     , digit('5')     , digit('0','5').

digit(V)       --> [V].
digit(Min,Max) --> [D], { D @>= Min, D @=< Max }.
```

You can fiddle with it at https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/dotted-quad-dcg.pl

Alternatively, if you don't want to use a DCG, then this riff off @Dudas's answer will work as well — but one should be aware that this is essentially what the above DCG is (DCG being an essentially simple bit of syntactic sugar on top of vanilla prolog), just a bit less declarative of intent:

```
is_dotted_quad(X)  :- atom(X)   , atom_chars(X,Cs)   , is_dotted_quad(Cs).
is_dotted_quad(X)  :- string(X) , string_chars(X,Cs) , is_dotted_quad(Cs).
is_dotted_quad(Cs) :- octet(Cs,T1),
          dot(T1,T2), octet(T2,T3),
          dot(T3,T4), octet(T4,T5),
          dot(T5,T6), octet(T6,[]).

chars( []     , []     ) .
chars( [C|Cs] , [C|Cs] ) .
chars( X      , Cs     ) :- atom(X)   , atom_chars(X,Cs) .
chars( X      , Cs     ) :- string(X) , string_chars(X,Cs) .

dot(['.'|T],T).

octet( [             Z | T ], T ) :- range(Z,'0','9') .
octet( [       Y   , Z | T ], T ) :- range(Y,'1','9') , range(Z,'0','9') .
octet( [ '1' , Y   , Z | T ], T ) :- range(Y,'0','9') , range(Z,'0','9') .
octet( [ '2' , Y   , Z | T ], T ) :- range(Y,'0','4') , range(Z,'0','9') .
octet( [ '2' , '5' , Z | T ], T ) :- range(Z,'0','5') .

range(X,Min,Max) :- X @>= Min, X @=< Max .
```